# TypeScript interface signature for the onClick event in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The official [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) website contains an excellent introductory tutorial.

The tutorial snippets are written in JavaScript and I am trying to convert these to TypeScript.

I have managed to get the code working but have a question about using interfaces.

What should the correct "function signature" be for the onClick callback.

***Is there a way to replace the 'any' keyword in the IProps_Square interface with an explicit function signature ?***

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated, many thanks Russell

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="reactjs-tutorial"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';   
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 

interface IProps_Square {
  message: string,
  onClick: any,
}

class Square extends React.Component < IProps_Square > {
   render() {  
     return (
       <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
         {this.props.message}
       </button>
     );
   }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Square
         message = { 'click this' }
         onClick = { () => alert('hello') }
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />, 
  document.getElementById('reactjs-tutorial')   
);
```

Comment: If you use WebStorm, you can Ctrl-click on the `onClick` attribute to view its type.

Comment: You can also replace `this.props.onClick` with some nonsense, e.g. `onClick={42}`. Then, when TypeScript rejects your program, it'll include the correct type in its error message.

Comment: @Lambda Fairy I used this method in Quasar event handler signature. const linkClick = (e: Event, go:((opts?: { to?: any; replace?: boolean | undefined; returnRouterError?: boolean | undefined; } | undefined) => Promise<any>) | undefined)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The *interface* with props should be

```js
interface IProps_Square {
  message: string;
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
}
```

Notice also that if you use semicolons, the interface items separator is a semicolon, not a comma.

Another hint: I recommend `type` rather than `interface` for props. They are almost the same, the only difference I found is that `interface` may be extended anywhere in the code, in fact it is used for globals.

Answer (score 31):

> Is there a way to replace the 'any' keyword in the IProps_Square interface with an explicit function signature

I would just `() => void` i.e. a function that takes no arguments and you don't care if it returns anything.

```
import * as React from 'react';   
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 

interface IProps_Square {
  message: string,
  onClick: () => void,
}

class Square extends React.Component < IProps_Square > {
   render() {  
     return (
       <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
         {this.props.message}
       </button>
     );
   }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Square
         message = { 'click this' }
         onClick = { () => alert('hello') }
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Game />, 
  document.getElementById('reactjs-tutorial')   
);
```

However if you need the parameter the proper type for it is `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>`, so:

```
interface IProps_Square {
  message: string,
  onClick: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void,
}
```

Comment: If he needs event as parameter he can also declare it as `onClick(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>):void`

Comment: This comment should be an answer.

Comment: Hi, what if you want to call or trigger a state back in the parent with the onClick event?

Comment: @Mahesh -- see [emerson marini's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54433183/typescript-interface-signature-for-the-onclick-event-in-reactjs#comment122110081_54433195).

Answer (score 4):

How do you declare the type for `handleClick`?

```
const Foo = (props: IFoo) => {
    return <button onClick={props.handleClick}></button>
}
```

You have two options:

```
interface IFoo {
    handleClick(e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void
}
```

```
interface IFoo {
    handleClick: (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void
}
```

Comment: can you share any tutorial on where you have learnt this?

Comment: @RohanDevaki I don't remember

Answer (score 2):

Except React.MouseEvent you can use

```
type IProps_Square = {
  onClick: React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>["onClick"];
}
```

or

```
type IProps_Square = {
  onClick: JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"]["onClick"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code stop complaining and was able to deploy with this

```
interface IVor {
    handleClick: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void
}

const VorButton = (props: IVor) => {
   return <button onClick={props.handleClick}>vor</button>
}
```